# How to calculate when two things 'meet'?

Tags: order-statistics

Scenario A: Let's say someone recieves money from his mother on 4th of December, and someone sends him money on an unknown day, what is the possibitlity for him to recieve the money on the same day?

Scenario B: Let's say someone recieves money from his mother on someday between 4th and 16th of December, and someone sends him money on an unknown day, what is the possibitlity for him to recieve the money on the same day?

Comment: Do you mean by "What's the possibility": what's the probability?

Comment: What are the possible days in which the person can receive the present from the unknown person?

Comment: When you say "on an unknown day", do you literally mean any? Is it possible that the day might be the 7th of June, 1883?

Comment: please clarify your question whether you need a probability or something else ,  if you simply want to know the probability  then for first one it will be 1/365 and for the next one taking both 4th and 16 th inclusive it will be 13/365   because there are 13 total days on which he can send the gift on and coincide with his mother's choice  assuming a normal year of 365 days

Comment: @Randomizer so you think the day has to be in the same year? January the first of the next year would seem like a much more likely day to get a present than august the fifth of that year.

Comment: @Randomizer using that logic if the mother could send present on any day of the year, then the probability they coincide would be 1. Which would be the same as saying the probability we have the same birthday is 1. Which I doubt highly.

Comment: Yes, What's the possibility. The unknown day is in the same year. I learn Maths in anothel language so it's hard to explain in English.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that you can narrow down the days in which you can receive the present from this rando stranger to an interval of n days (which contain all days from the 4th to the thirteenth of december).

Then the probability that this person sends the person in th efourth of december. Assuming each day is equally likely is $\dfrac{1}{n}$ this is because there are n possible outcomes(each with probability $\dfrac{1}{n}$, and only one of them gets the present in the 4th.

Now:what is the probability they both receive the present on the same day if the mother can send the present on any day between the 4th and 16th. There are 13 days in this interval. Look at the pairs (x,y) where x is the day you get the present prom your mother and y the day you get the present from the father. There are $13n$ such pairs since there are 13 possible days the mother can send the present and $n$ days the stranger can send the present. So then by the [rule of product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product) there are 13n pairs. Out of these 13n pairs there are clearly only 13 where the person receives both at the same time. Namely the pairs $(4,4),(5,5),(6,6)\dots(13,13),(14,14)$ Assuming all pairs are equally likely there are 13 pairs that achieve what we want and 13n total pairs, so the probability is again $\dfrac{1}{n}$